# Why does CloudFront deliver sequential connections that cancel out? Img inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are using signed URLs to deliver some video content. When browsing directly to the signed URL, looking at the network profiler, you can see the URL being connected to 4 times. Why is it doing this?

The screen shot below was a brand new, generated link so in no way was this file cached. The reason I am even to this point is cloudFront has been extremely slow to load videos for us the past week. The video in the screen shot is an hour and a half and it takes about 20-30 seconds to begin playing.

The same exact file we place on rackspace begins playing within 5 seconds.

[view larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLLTE.jpg)
[image][view larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLLTE.jpg)

what happens is the first line cancels out right away, the second line begins to download and at about 3.5mb downloaded it cancels and starts the 3rd and 4th lines. The 4th line is finally the file that begins downloading and playing

Comment: Did you check if these requests are for full object, or for ranges? 206 response means that partial content is being fetched. Also looking at the times I see only ~10 second delay before playback start, not 20-30 seconds. I'm not trying to say there is no issue, but rather that it might not be completely captured in the screenshot.

Comment: @Fahrenheit2539 It is the beginning of the file so not sure why it would be doing a partial content download. The 10 seconds you are seeing is the 2nd line. Once that happens, it cancels the download and 2 more subsequent ones begin (3 and 4). Line 4 is finally the file that works and plays and that is about 5 seconds. Between all 4 of those connections this particular request took about 18 seconds. It seems to vary. We found that cloudfront doesn't cache files for very long, unless accessed frequently, so that may be why its taking so long to start up.