# Why does AWS keep canceling my download request and then starting over?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS (s3/cloudfront) to deliver some MP4 video content to my iOS app.

I am trying to play a rather large file (197mb to be exact).

I am watching the requests using Charles Proxy and I am noticing it calls the URL multiple times and gives 206 response code. I had a similar question not too long ago that went unanswered, but it was happening in chrome on the web ([Why does CloudFront deliver sequential connections that cancel out? Img inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981372/why-does-cloudfront-deliver-sequential-connections-that-cancel-out-img-inside))

I am throttling my connection using charles to 3G x2 and it takes over a minute to begin playing the video. I am wondering if it is because all those requests that keep getting cancelled.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtKg3.png) is a screen shot of the requests
[image]

[This shows "Client closed connection before receiving entire response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxSrh.png)
[image]

Comment: 206 is not a failure code, it's a successful "partial content" response to a request that included a Range header to request a specific part of the S3 object rather than the whole thing.

Comment: I know it isn't a failure code, but why so many requests? Why is it taking more than a minute to begin playing my file? I used to use limelight to deliver our MP4s and they would start almost instantly, even on slow connections. Coming from cloudfront, it is just terrible.

Comment: I am also noticing it saying their is a failure. See my edit @IanRoberts

Comment: Regardless of what you believe happened in another environment, you need to be familiar with a couple of concepts.  First, the "client" is the player.  "Client closed connection..." suggests a problem with the client.  Second, a server does not respond with a 206 unless requested by the client... this is a question for the client, not the server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I know client is the player. My client never exhibited this behavior when I was on a different CDN. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=459195